# Joomla search 404

Tags: php, search, joomla, http-status-code-404

Is there a extension that, when you enter a page that doesn't exist, redirects you to the search page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla error pages are typically handled by JOOMLA/templates/YOUR TEMPLATE/error.php. You can either customize that page or you can put a redirect on the page to get visitors where you want them to end up. Since most people don't include one of these in their template, it defaults back to the system file. You can copy the on in JOOMLA/templates/system/error.php to get started.

http://docs.joomla.org/Custom_error_pages

Comment: thanks but I know I can do this, I want a search 404, that is much better than a simple page error

Comment: You can put any code you want on the error page. If you want a search 404 then redirect to the Joomla search with the related query string in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

There is no module available AFAIK - at least not for 1.6. But it is quite easy to do by yourself.
You can use the solution in the joomla documentation. This is usable for any error code.

http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Custom_404_Error_Page

```
if (($this->error->code) == '404') {
header('Location: /search');
exit;
}
```

The part behind the Location: is where you redirect to the page you want. e.g. /search in this case.
The above is for 1.5, for 1.6 you need to use this:

```
  if ($this->error->getCode() == '404') {
          header('Location: /search');
          exit;
  } ;
```

The second possible solution if you are using apache is to use modify the .htaccess file in the root of the joomla installation - if you can't find one create one - and add this snippet to redirect to the page you want for error code 404 (page not found).

```
# CUSTOM ERROR PAGES
 ErrorDocument 404 URL /search
# END CUSTOM ERROR PAGES
```

If you need more assistance please don't hesitate to ask.